# Django guardian migration NodeNotFoundError after MIGRATION_MODULES defined for auth

Tags: python, django, django-migrations, django-settings, django-guardian

I used `django` guardian in my project. For a reason, I added a new field to `django` group model with this code:

```
if not hasattr(Group, 'project'):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='groups')
    project.contribute_to_class(Group, 'project')
```

So far, everything is ok. But I realized after `makemigration` command, django adds migration file to outside of my project directory. I want to make this file persistent. I found a solution with defining `MIGRATION_MODULES` in my `settings.py`:

```
MIGRATION_MODULES = {
  'auth': 'preferences.migrations' # preferences is an app of mine
}
```

But this time, django guardian module gives error after `makemigration` command. The errors are below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./manage.py", line 16, in 
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 375, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_cassandra_engine/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 22, in handle
>       super(Command, self).handle(*args, **options)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
>       res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 87, in handle
>       loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in **init**
>       self.build_graph()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 274, in build_graph
>       raise exc
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 248, in build_graph
>       self.graph.validate_consistency()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 195, in validate_consistency
>       [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 195, in 
>       [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 58, in raise_error
>       raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
>   django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration auth.0012_group_project dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('projects', '0001_initial')

I tried add guardian to `MIGRATION_MODULES` definitions. But this time, migrations generated wrongly. After I tried `migrate` command it gives this errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./manage.py", line 16, in 
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 375, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_cassandra_engine/management/commands/migrate.py", line 13, in handle
>       return super(Command, self).handle(*args, **options)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
>       res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 87, in handle
>       executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in **init**
>       self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in **init**
>       self.build_graph()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 275, in build_graph
>       self.graph.ensure_not_cyclic()
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 274, in ensure_not_cyclic
>       raise CircularDependencyError(", ".join("%s.%s" % n for n in cycle))
>   django.db.migrations.exceptions.CircularDependencyError: users.0001_initial, accounts.0002_account_owner, projects.0001_initial, auth.0002_auto_20200426_0201, auth.0001_initial

In generated migration files, dependencies sections are(in preferences app which migration_modules definitions point):

001_initial.py:

```
 dependencies = [
    ('auth', '0002_auto_20200426_0201'),
    migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
]
```

0002_auto_20200426_0201.py

```
dependencies = [
    ('auth', '0001_initial'),
    ('projects', '0001_initial'),
]
```

Where is my error? How can I solve this problem? I'm very confused.

Comment: You shouldn't use this method to add fields to the `Group` model, there are quite a few potential issues with it, including the one you are having. You should instead look at adding a custom user model with a foreign key to a custom Group model https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model